# How to use templated delegate

Tags: c#, templates, generics, delegates

I'm trying to use a templated delegate in one of my class.

Here the class definition :

```
internal class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public delegate T Create<T>(int identity) where T : SomeOtherClass;
    public Create<T> CreateCB {get;set;}    //<-- This here doesn't compile
}
```

I will use the `CreateCB` such as this

```
return CreateCB<InheritedClassFromSomeOtherClass>(someId);
```

and

```
return CreateCB<OtherInheritedClassFromSomeOtherClass>(someId);
```

etc.

I can't template the whole `MyClass` since it will need to use the delegate to create many different type who inherit from `SomeOtherClass`

The line who doesn't compile don't need to be a property but I still need to use my generic templated delegate. How can I do this?

My app target .net 4 client profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `T` is scoped to the delegate, but the `T` you're trying to use in the property is undefined.

Your problem here is that there is no such thing as a generic property, therefore you can't define `T`.

There are two workarounds:

- Make the class generic, so `T` is defined everywhere:

  ```
  internal class MyClass<T> : BaseClass
      where T : SomeOtherClass
  {
      public delegate T Create(int identity);

      // Now T is in scope
      public Create CreateCB { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Use a getter/setter pair, if you really can't make the class generic, but this is... *ugly*:

  ```
  internal class MyClass : BaseClass
  {
      private object _createCB;

      public delegate T Create<T>(int identity)
          where T : SomeOtherClass;

      public Create<T> GetCreateCB<T>()
          where T : SomeOtherClass;
      {
          return (Create<T>)_createCB;
      }

      public void SetCreateCB<T>(Create<T> fn)
          where T : SomeOtherClass;
      {
          _createCB = fn;
      }
  }
  ```

  Hopefully this snippet shows why there's no such thing as a generic property in the first place. You lose the strong typing anyway because of the storage. And you have to provide `T` explicitly on each get/set - you'd better be coherent with that.

Comment: I think you mean `public delegate T Create<T>(int identity);` in the first example. This is what I suspected. Unfortunatly I can't template the whole class and the other solution could work but as you say it is ugly. Thank you for your answer. I will see if I can try to rework this so I don't need the templated delegate

Comment: No I didn't mean `Create<T>` as this would redefine the `T`. The full delegate class name is `MyClass<T>.Create` and it's still generic. You could move it to a nongeneric class and reintroduce the `T` though.